# SQL Server: Replace a list of ASCII characters from a VARCHAR(MAX) field

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with around 4 million records and I need to remove any instance of the ASCII characters in the following range(s) in a `VARCHAR(MAX)` column.

- 00 - 08
- 11 - 12
- 14 - 31
- 127

Please note the above represent the decimal identifiers for each character, the actual ASCII characters to be replaced can be crosschecked against http://www.asciitable.com/.

I have tried the following ways and achieved the desired results.

First way: using nested `REPLACE` functions:

```
UPDATE [MyTable] 
SET replace_ascii_chars = REPLACE(REPLACE(replace_ascii_chars, char(0), '') 
,char(1), '')....
```

Second way: created the following SQL function and ran an `UPDATE` statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].RemoveASCIICharactersInRange(@InputString VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @InputString IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @Counter INT, @TestString NVARCHAR(40)

      SET @TestString = '%[' + NCHAR(0) + NCHAR(1) + NCHAR(2) + NCHAR(3) + NCHAR(4) + NCHAR(5) + NCHAR(6) + NCHAR(7) + NCHAR(8) + NCHAR(11) + NCHAR(12) + NCHAR(14) + NCHAR(15) + NCHAR(16) + NCHAR(17) + NCHAR(18) + NCHAR(19) + NCHAR(20) + NCHAR(21) + NCHAR(22) + NCHAR(23) + NCHAR(24) + NCHAR(25) + NCHAR(26) + NCHAR(27) + NCHAR(28) + NCHAR(29) + NCHAR(30) + NCHAR(31) + NCHAR(127)+ ']%'

      SELECT @Counter = PATINDEX (@TestString, @InputString COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)

      WHILE @Counter <> 0
      BEGIN
        SELECT @InputString = STUFF(@InputString, @Counter, 1, '')
        SELECT @Counter = PATINDEX (@TestString, @InputString COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)
      END
    END
    RETURN(@InputString)
END
```

UPDATE SQL:

```
UPDATE [MyTable] 
SET replace_ascii_chars = [dbo].RemoveASCIICharactersInRange(replace_ascii_chars)
```

Both the aforementioned ways worked fine but seems to be a bit slow (taking around 1.5 hours). Is there way to speed it up in SQL Server? I do not want to do the replacements in the application layer as the values are already saved in this way.

Also, not all 4 million records do not have these characters, so is there a way to speed it up?

EDIT: 
I was wrong in saying WHERE clause taking longer (it was slower because of the way I used where clause earlier). I have updated the where clause as per @MWillemse suggestion and it seems to be very fast now.

Comment: 1) Make several, smaller transactions. 2) Do not update rows not containing those unwanted characters. (I.e. add where clause.)

Comment: Because it is in the database does not mean the database is the best tool for the task.  I would do this in an application like .NET.  Or write a CLR to do it.

Comment: Have you tried this: `WHERE data LIKE '%['+CHAR(0)+','+CHAR(1)+','+CHAR(2)+','+CHAR(3)+','+CHAR(4)+']%'`

Comment: Thank you @MWillemse for your suggestion. Thank you jarlh, Balm for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is now running faster after I have added a WHERE clause as per @MWillemse suggestion.

```
UPDATE [MyTable] 
SET replace_ascii_chars = REPLACE(REPLACE(replace_ascii_chars, char(0), '') 
,char(1), '')....
WHERE replace_ascii_chars LIKE '%[' + CHAR(0) + CHAR(1) + CHAR(2) + CHAR(3) + CHAR(4) + CHAR(5) + CHAR(6) + CHAR(7) + CHAR(8) + CHAR(11) + CHAR(12) + CHAR(14) + CHAR(15) + CHAR(16) + CHAR(17) + CHAR(18) + CHAR(19) + CHAR(20) + CHAR(21) + CHAR(22) + CHAR(23) + CHAR(24) + CHAR(25) + CHAR(26) + CHAR(27) + CHAR(28) + CHAR(29) + CHAR(30) + CHAR(31) + CHAR(127)+ ']%'
```

Thank you @MWillemse, @jarlh, @Balm for your valuable comments.

**EDIT:** Please note this would work only from `SQL SERVER 2012` and above. Please follow this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884135/sql-query-working-fine-in-sql-server-2012-but-failed-to-execute-in-sql-server-2) for discussion on issues with LOB data types and certain collations when used with `REPLACE` function in older `SQL Server` versions.