# SQL query working fine in SQL Server 2012, but failed to execute in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a table called `MyTextstable (myTextsTable_id INT, myTextsTable_text VARCHAR(MAX))`. This table has around 4 million records and I am trying to remove any instance of the `ASCII` characters in the following range(s) the `VARCHAR(MAX)` column `myTextsTable_text`.

- 00 - 08
- 11 - 12
- 14 - 31
- 127

I have written the following SQL query, which is taking under 10 minutes on SQL Server 2012, but failed to execute on SQL Server 2008 R2 even after two hours (so I stopped the execution). Please note I have restored the backup of a SQL Server 2008 R2 database on SQL Server 2012 (i.e. the data is exactly same).

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]

BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE myTextsTable
    SET myTextsTable_text = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(myTextsTable_text, CHAR(0), ''), CHAR(1), ''), CHAR(2), ''), CHAR(3), ''), CHAR(4), ''), CHAR(5), ''), CHAR(6), ''), CHAR(7), ''), CHAR(8), ''), CHAR(11), ''), CHAR(12), ''), CHAR(14), ''), CHAR(15), ''), CHAR(16), ''), CHAR(17), ''), CHAR(18), ''), CHAR(19), ''), CHAR(20), ''), CHAR(21), ''), CHAR(22), ''), CHAR(23), ''), CHAR(24), ''), CHAR(25), ''), CHAR(26), ''), CHAR(27), ''), CHAR(28), ''), CHAR(29), ''), CHAR(30), ''), CHAR(31), ''), CHAR(127), '')
    WHERE myTextsTable_text LIKE '%[' + CHAR(0) + CHAR(1) + CHAR(2) + CHAR(3) + CHAR(4) + CHAR(5) + CHAR(6) + CHAR(7) + CHAR(8) + CHAR(11) + CHAR(12) + CHAR(14) + CHAR(15) + CHAR(16) + CHAR(17) + CHAR(18) + CHAR(19) + CHAR(20) + CHAR(21) + CHAR(22) + CHAR(23) + CHAR(24) + CHAR(25) + CHAR(26) + CHAR(27) + CHAR(28) + CHAR(29) + CHAR(30) + CHAR(31) + CHAR(127) + ']%';
    COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1];
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1];
    --PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH;
```

There are only 135 records affected. As the single `UPDATE` query wasn't working in SQL Server 2008, I have tried the following approach with a temp table.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]

BEGIN TRY
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTextsTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #myTextsTable;
    SELECT myTextsTable_id, myTextsTable_text
    INTO #myTextsTable
    FROM myTextsTable
    WHERE myTextsTable_text LIKE '%[' + CHAR(0) + CHAR(1) + CHAR(2) + CHAR(3) + CHAR(4) + CHAR(5) + CHAR(6) + CHAR(7) + CHAR(8) + CHAR(11) + CHAR(12) + CHAR(14) + CHAR(15) + CHAR(16) + CHAR(17) + CHAR(18) + CHAR(19) + CHAR(20) + CHAR(21) + CHAR(22) + CHAR(23) + CHAR(24) + CHAR(25) + CHAR(26) + CHAR(27) + CHAR(28) + CHAR(29) + CHAR(30) + CHAR(31) + CHAR(127) + ']%';

    UPDATE #myTextsTable
    SET myTextsTable_text = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(myTextsTable_text, CHAR(0), ''), CHAR(1), ''), CHAR(2), ''), CHAR(3), ''), CHAR(4), ''), CHAR(5), ''), CHAR(6), ''), CHAR(7), ''), CHAR(8), ''), CHAR(11), ''), CHAR(12), ''), CHAR(14), ''), CHAR(15), ''), CHAR(16), ''), CHAR(17), ''), CHAR(18), ''), CHAR(19), ''), CHAR(20), ''), CHAR(21), ''), CHAR(22), ''), CHAR(23), ''), CHAR(24), ''), CHAR(25), ''), CHAR(26), ''), CHAR(27), ''), CHAR(28), ''), CHAR(29), ''), CHAR(30), ''), CHAR(31), ''), CHAR(127), '')

    UPDATE myTextsTable
    SET myTextsTable_text = new.myTextsTable_text
    FROM myTextsTable
    INNER JOIN #myTextsTable new ON new.myTextsTable_id=myTextsTable.myTextsTable_id

    DROP TABLE #myTextsTable;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1];
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1];
    --PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH;
```

However, the result is same. Works perfectly fine in SQL Server 2012, but not in SQL Server 2008 R2. I found that the `UPDATE` query was still executing even after two hours (the records were saved into the temp table (`#myTextsTable`) in a few minutes, I checked this later to make sure which part is taking longer).

As the aforementioned two ways weren't working, I have tried using this using `TABLE` variables just to check if it makes any difference, but the result was same (i.e. works fine in SQL Server 2012 but not in SQL Server 2008 R2)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]

BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @myTextsTable TABLE (myTextsTable_id INT, myTextsTable_text VARCHAR(MAX))
    INSERT INTO @myTextsTable(myTextsTable_id, myTextsTable_text)
    SELECT myTextsTable_id, myTextsTable_text
    FROM myTextsTable
    WHERE myTextsTable_text LIKE '%[' + CHAR(0) + CHAR(1) + CHAR(2) + CHAR(3) + CHAR(4) + CHAR(5) + CHAR(6) + CHAR(7) + CHAR(8) + CHAR(11) + CHAR(12) + CHAR(14) + CHAR(15) + CHAR(16) + CHAR(17) + CHAR(18) + CHAR(19) + CHAR(20) + CHAR(21) + CHAR(22) + CHAR(23) + CHAR(24) + CHAR(25) + CHAR(26) + CHAR(27) + CHAR(28) + CHAR(29) + CHAR(30) + CHAR(31) + CHAR(127) + ']%';

    UPDATE @myTextsTable
    SET myTextsTable_text = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(myTextsTable_text, CHAR(0), ''), CHAR(1), ''), CHAR(2), ''), CHAR(3), ''), CHAR(4), ''), CHAR(5), ''), CHAR(6), ''), CHAR(7), ''), CHAR(8), ''), CHAR(11), ''), CHAR(12), ''), CHAR(14), ''), CHAR(15), ''), CHAR(16), ''), CHAR(17), ''), CHAR(18), ''), CHAR(19), ''), CHAR(20), ''), CHAR(21), ''), CHAR(22), ''), CHAR(23), ''), CHAR(24), ''), CHAR(25), ''), CHAR(26), ''), CHAR(27), ''), CHAR(28), ''), CHAR(29), ''), CHAR(30), ''), CHAR(31), ''), CHAR(127), '')

    UPDATE myTextsTable
    SET myTextsTable_updated = GETDATE()
        ,myTextsTable_updatedby = 'As per V87058'
        ,myTextsTable_text = new.myTextsTable_text
    FROM myTextsTable
    INNER JOIN @myTextsTable new ON new.myTextsTable_id=myTextsTable.myTextsTable_id

    COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1];
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1];
    --PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH;
```

Could anyone explain why this would happen? How to make this SQL query work in SQL Server 2008 R2?

**Note:** I know that the string manipulations in database server/layer are not ideal and it would be recommended to do string manipulations in application layer and then save it in DB. But, I am trying to understand why this would be a problem in one version and why not in another version.

> SQL Server 2012
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)
>   Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )
>   (Hypervisor)
>
> SQL Server 2008 R2
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)
>   Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )
>   (Hypervisor)

Comment: Instead of Table variable try TempTable.

Comment: @SelvaTS: Thank you for your comment. I have tried temp table before trying it with TABLE vatable as mentioned in my question.

Comment: It could be quite longer, but I'll try to do divide into around 30 queries (or by using a loop), to replace characters one by one: `UPDATE myTextsTable SET myTextsTable_text = REPLACE(myTextsTable_text, CHAR(0), '') WHERE myTextsTable_text LIKE '%[' + CHAR(0) + ']%';` that would avoid too many imbricated REPLACE. And, in this case, maybe CHARINDEX instead of LIKE.

Comment: @Rubik: That's on board, I am trying it now. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Just to be sure.  Select where works fine?  It is definitely the update set that is causing the problems?  A single statement is a transaction.  Unless you have other stuff going on you don't need that explicit transaction.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/708179/indefinite-hang-with-replace-statement-on-varbinary-max

Comment: @Blam: Yes, the select statement is working fine. I agree with your comment related to the `TRANSACTION` usage.

Comment: A reach but does your 2008 R2 have all SP and patches?  It seems like a bad replace - like it is in an internal loop.   How big is the data.  I might be a varchar(max) issue.  Could you fit in in a varchar(x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/708179/indefinite-hang-with-replace-statement-on-varbinary-max) on SQL Server 2008 with LOB datatypes and certain collations.

It is easy to reproduce

```
/*Hangs on 2008*/

DECLARE @VcMax varchar(max)= char(0) + 'a'

SELECT REPLACE(@VcMax COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, char(0), '')
```

Whilst hung it is CPU bound and seems to be in an infinite loop through these functions.

[image]

And the fix is easy too. Either use a non `MAX` datatype...

... or a binary collation

```
/*Doesn't Hang*/
DECLARE @VcMax varchar(max)= char(0) + 'a'

SELECT REPLACE(@VcMax COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2, char(0), '')
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try this now, but could you please clarify why do we need to `CAST @VBMax` variable in your example (it is been declared as a `VARCHAR(MAX)` field)?

Comment: @Sathish - No need at all. It's because I just copied the code out of the connect item I submitted and there it was using `varbinary(max)`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I had thought that would be the case. Would you mind to explain what is the image attached to your answer? Is it possible to produce it in SSMS or do we need to use any other tool?

Comment: @Sathish - It is from attaching the code profiler in Visual Studio to the SQL Server process whilst it was hung with busy CPU.

Comment: Thank you, Martin Smith. The Binary Collation worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this in future, the following ways worked fine.

Way 1.  Changing the `COLLATION` on the `VARCHAR(MAX)` column in the `UPDATE SQL` query to `BINARY COLLATION` as Martin Smith suggested (please see the accepted answer).

> REPLACE(myTextsTable_text COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2, CHAR(0),...

The solution will be as below:

```
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]

BEGIN TRY
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTextsTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #myTextsTable;
    SELECT myTextsTable_id, myTextsTable_text
    INTO #myTextsTable
    FROM myTextsTable
    WHERE myTextsTable_text LIKE '%[' + CHAR(0) + CHAR(1) + CHAR(2) + CHAR(3) + CHAR(4) + CHAR(5) + CHAR(6) + CHAR(7) + CHAR(8) + CHAR(11) + CHAR(12) + CHAR(14) + CHAR(15) + CHAR(16) + CHAR(17) + CHAR(18) + CHAR(19) + CHAR(20) + CHAR(21) + CHAR(22) + CHAR(23) + CHAR(24) + CHAR(25) + CHAR(26) + CHAR(27) + CHAR(28) + CHAR(29) + CHAR(30) + CHAR(31) + CHAR(127) + ']%';

    UPDATE #myTextsTable
    SET myTextsTable_text = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(myTextsTable_text COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2, CHAR(0), ''), CHAR(1), ''), CHAR(2), ''), CHAR(3), ''), CHAR(4), ''), CHAR(5), ''), CHAR(6), ''), CHAR(7), ''), CHAR(8), ''), CHAR(11), ''), CHAR(12), ''), CHAR(14), ''), CHAR(15), ''), CHAR(16), ''), CHAR(17), ''), CHAR(18), ''), CHAR(19), ''), CHAR(20), ''), CHAR(21), ''), CHAR(22), ''), CHAR(23), ''), CHAR(24), ''), CHAR(25), ''), CHAR(26), ''), CHAR(27), ''), CHAR(28), ''), CHAR(29), ''), CHAR(30), ''), CHAR(31), ''), CHAR(127), '')

    UPDATE myTextsTable
    SET myTextsTable_updated = GETDATE()
        ,myTextsTable_updatedby = 'As per V87058'
        ,myTextsTable_text = new.myTextsTable_text
    FROM myTextsTable
    INNER JOIN #myTextsTable new ON new.myTextsTable_id=myTextsTable.myTextsTable_id

    DROP TABLE #myTextsTable;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1];
END TRY
```

Way 2:
I have created a `SQL function` to replace these characters with `STUFF` instead of using `REPLACE` function.

> Note: Please note the SQL function is written to my specific
>   requirement. As such, it only replaces characters in the following
>   range.

- 00 - 08
- 11 - 12
- 14 - 31
- 127

--

```
Go
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].RemoveASCIICharactersInRange(@InputString VARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
        IF @InputString IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
          DECLARE @Counter INT, @TestString NVARCHAR(40)

          SET @TestString = '%[' + NCHAR(0) + NCHAR(1) + NCHAR(2) + NCHAR(3) + NCHAR(4) + NCHAR(5) + NCHAR(6) + NCHAR(7) + NCHAR(8) + NCHAR(11) + NCHAR(12) + NCHAR(14) + NCHAR(15) + NCHAR(16) + NCHAR(17) + NCHAR(18) + NCHAR(19) + NCHAR(20) + NCHAR(21) + NCHAR(22) + NCHAR(23) + NCHAR(24) + NCHAR(25) + NCHAR(26) + NCHAR(27) + NCHAR(28) + NCHAR(29) + NCHAR(30) + NCHAR(31) + NCHAR(127)+ ']%'

          SELECT @Counter = PATINDEX (@TestString, @InputString COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)

          WHILE @Counter <> 0
          BEGIN
            SELECT @InputString = STUFF(@InputString, @Counter, 1, '')
            SELECT @Counter = PATINDEX (@TestString, @InputString COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)
          END
        END
        RETURN(@InputString)
    END

    GO
```

Then, the `UPDATE SQL` query (in my temp table approach) will be something like below:

```
UPDATE #myTextsTable 
SET myTextsTable_text = [dbo].RemoveASCIICharactersInRange(#myTextsTable_text)
Go
```

My personal preferred way would be the first one.

Answer (score -1):

Probably the problem is the nesting in the replace and it is reported on the execution and not the compilación check @@nestlevel function. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190607(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: `@@nestlevel` doesn't apply to built in functions and wouldn't cause an indefinite hang if exceeded anyway. And it is easy to reproduce with a single `REPLACE`.